# Timezone difference of browser and server

Tags: javascript, php, momentjs

I have been using *momentjs* for detecting *timezone* of user (client side). I have PHP `timezone_identifiers_list()` function for server timezone list.

Issue I am facing right now is, *momentjs* is returning timezone as *'Asia/Calcutta'* and PHP is returning it as *'Asia/Kolkata'*. Both are same but giving me a reverse effect.

Is there any way to match both these? Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: I tend to be of the school where I will only use date objects from javascript if _ABSOLUTELY_ necessary. If you think it might be the case where you could simply just deal with the date information via PHP, that might save you the headache. Otherwise, I'd recommend what @CodingNoob said

Comment: What do you mean "giving me a reverse effect"?  Those two zones are identical, one is just an alias for the other.  And what code are you using for the moment.js side?

Comment: code for moment js `var browser_timezone = moment.tz.guess();` , this gives me the output 'Asia/Calcutta' and I have one php variable which gives me the output as 'Asia/Kolkata', which is the output from `timezone_identifiers_list()`. So basically both are same but the different spelling causing me the problem.It gives the user an alert message saying "timezone different". I hope you get it now

Comment: We do understand, but please understand what we are saying. Do not compare strings. Compare timezones as values. Calcutta is in timezone +5:30 hours. Use that to compare with.

Comment: you mean timezone offset value?

Comment: @Andreas Time zones have multiple offsets, and multiple timezones share the same offset, but have different DST transition dates, etc. DO NOT compare offsets to establish if you have the right time zone. I explain this in detail in this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ieIzNP6gKqU

Comment: @akhil I'm pretty sure you have something fundamentally incorrect going on RE the way you are handling time. If your code relies on the browser being in the same timezone as the server, restructuring needs to be done. If you need help with this, you can go in the Moment.js gitter and we'll see what we can do.

Comment: @MaggiePint got something that is about one hour less? What he wants is to know if the user is in the same timezone as server. And a number is far better than strings. I know that for example +1 h has several timezones such as Paris, Copenhagen, Stockholm etc. But since the user is not forced to have the correct timezone "string" then why use it to compare? For example I live closer to Copenhagen than Stockholm so I use Copenhagen as my timezone even though that is a different country than  I live in. How are you supposed to know if the user has the correct timezone?

Comment: I would not be surprised if some immigrants have their home timezone on their computers, or people on holliday. I think it's foolish to not compare the numbers only, the strings/timezones can be way off.

Answer (score 3):

Try using UTC and then adding or subtracting time on/off based on location.

Comment: Can you give me a reference link or something??

Answer (score 2):

I have not used moment.js, but looking at the documentation http://momentjs.com/timezone/ it seems as you can get the time in zulu time.

```
dec.tz('Asia/Calcutta').format('ha z');
// where dec is your moment time.
```

In php you can do the same-ish

```
echo gmdate('H', strtotime(time()));
// this should return the + or - hours your server time is from UTC/zulu
```

With those two values you can calcluate  what time it is at the user.

Comment: This was really helpful , thank you. But what I exactly need is to show user an alert message if there is a timezone difference between server and client. I was checking the php returned timezone with moment js one. Then this spelling mistake came in. Is there anything you can suggest for resolving this issue?

Comment: The code above does not look at the timezone as a name, but as a timevalue. So London is 0, central europe is 1, east europe is 2 etc.

Comment: @akhil was my explenation enough?

Comment: @akhil I'm not sure how. Do you want me to explain how the planet spins and how that relates to time? The only thing I can help you with, given how little information an code you gave us, is: pass the timevalue (as in the code above) from php to javascript. Save the timevalue from moment.js to a javascript variable. Then it's just a "if" and a "alert" and your done.